# SQL Server stored procedure that would enforce atomicity?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have following insert statements

```
INSERT INTO tEmpl  (lastName)  VALUES('Smith')
INSERT INTO tEmpl  (lastName) VALUES('Jones')
INSERT INTO tEmpl  (lastName) VALUES('Smitty')
INSERT INTO tEmpl  (lastName) VALUES('Smithson')
GO
```

What stored procedure would enforce atomicity? I mean, all inserts have to be executed at once or none of them. Please give examples. I am still learning SQL Server.

Comment: Use transaction with Try Catch. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31279/transaction-and-try-catch-in-sql-server-job

Comment: what about begin atomic?

Comment: ["BEGIN ATOMIC is part of the ANSI SQL standard. SQL Server supports atomic blocks only at the top-level of natively compiled stored procedures."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452281.aspx)

Comment: "*all inserts have to be executed at once or none of them*" - that's precisely what a transaction is for. Assim's answer does exactly that. A transaction is atomic by definition.

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO tEmpl  (lastName)  VALUES('Smith'),('Jones'),('Smitty'),('Smithson') 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Transaction committed successfully'

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
ROLLBACK
PRINT 'Transaction rolled back'

END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks for example. But can it be implemented by using BEGIN ATOMIC?

Comment: There is no syntax like BEGIN ATOMIC. You can only give transaction a name like BEGIN TRANSACTION ATOMIC .....COMMIT TRANSACTION ATOMIC

Comment: @aasim.abdullah Sorry but you're wrong. Begin atomic is a statement by itself and it's also a part of the ANSI standard...